# setDate method overriding original date

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript `setDate` method to do some date manipulation due to which my value of `originalDate` value is lost. Here is what I am trying :

```
var originalDate = new Date();
var newDate = originalDate;
newDate.setDate(15);
```

I want that `setDate()` should only update `newDate` variable, not the originalDate. How can I do  that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are assigning the reference of `originalDate` to `newDate`, so they both point at the same `Date` object.

Another possibility:

Javascript

```
function cloneDate(dateObject) {
    return new Date(dateObject.valueOf());
}

var originalDate = new Date(),
    newDate = cloneDate(originalDate);

newDate.setDate(15);

console.log(originalDate);
console.log(newDate);
```

Output

```
Tue Feb 25 2014 07:13:53 GMT+0100 (CET)
Sat Feb 15 2014 07:13:53 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/QBs37/)

This creates `newDate` with same value as `originalDate`, but now they are 2 distinct objects
.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var originalDate = new Date();
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setDate(15);
```

Comment: This answer assumes that both dates are initially the same simply because they're called in quick succession. But this assumption is not guaranteed, and fails in any case if the `originalDate` is generated elsewhere in the code. This is **guaranteed** to introduce subtle bugs in the distant future when weird dates with the expected day but unexpected year and month appear everywhere in the app and nobody remembers why `newDate` wasn't exactly equal to `originalDate` before calling `setDate`.